# read specific lines from the file

Tags: text-processing, read

I have some text file (for example json). I can use `head` order for the reading of the first lines. For example:

```
head -n 100 file.json
```

get me 100 first lines back. What is Linux order, which I can use to read some general lines somewhere in file? For example from the line 500 to the line 700.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -n 500,700p file.json
```